# Execute multiple templates in go

Tags: go

I have this variable and I wanted to know if I can execute multiple templates
and if I can't do it with this variable then what should I do ?

```golang
var (
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("web/Pages/*"))
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "execute multiple templates"? You get a `*Template` which contains multiple named templates, any of which you can execute as many times as you want.

Comment: Multiple as in: at once? No, you can't. Multiple as in: execute them individually using a single variable? Yes, you can use the ExecuteTemplate method and pass in the name of the template you want to execute.

Comment: for example I want to do this: 
`
templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "a.html" , "b.html" , "c.html" , nil)
`

Comment: You can't do that. But you can "link" them by having `a.html` include `b.html` and `c.html` using the `{{ template <name> }}` action.

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Comment: but what if I have a base template?

Comment: The base should be included by the non-base template, and then you execute the non-base template.

Comment: would you please explain more or give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include templates in other templates by using the `{{ template "name" }}` action.

Say you have file `a.html`:

```
<p>this is A</p>
```

then you can include it in `b.html` like this:

```
{{ template "a.html" }}
<p>this is B</p>
```

and then if you run `templates.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "b.html", nil)` you'll get:

```
<p>this is A</p>
<p>this is B</p>
```

See the playground link for a more fleshed out example: https://play.golang.com/p/W0whRWlX119